# list of widgets of a dynamic app in integration test flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

I am learning [integration_test](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/introduction) for my dynamic app.

The home screen may contain any number (normally 9-13) of  Widgets (including 4/6 bottom Nav items) of different types depending on the location and server configurations of that user. So, Home Screen is building dynamically and varies from user to user.

I am trying to find a way to get the list of Widgets on the home screen and Tap them serially in the integration test. Is there any way to perform this task?

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably include some code regarding your question and also include the solution you have tried. This helps other users to understand the question better and give a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should know which widgets will be there based on the user you use for each test. Therefore you should interact with them accordingly